RazorViewEngine GetView function stopped working

I get an error that it can't find the view. It worked fine until a few
days ago. Maybe I installed a Windows update, and it caused the
problem?

  public class ViewSvc(
      IRazorViewEngine razorViewEngine,
      ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
      IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
  {

      public async Task<string> RenderViewToStringAsync<TModel>(string viewPath)
      {
          using var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
    
          var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext() { RequestServices = scope.ServiceProvider };
    
          var actionContext = new ActionContext(
                httpContext,
                new RouteData(),
                new ActionDescriptor());
    
          var viewResult = razorViewEngine.GetView(viewPath, viewPath, false);
    
          if (!viewResult.Success)
          {
              throw new Exception($"Couldn't find view '{viewPath}'");
          }
    }
}


string html = await viewSvc.RenderViewToStringAsync("~/Views/EmailApproveAccount.cshtml")


cshtml page

@using Infra.Utils.Config;
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@using Services.Core;
@model Services.Reg.Entities.EmailApproveAccountModel;
@inject ConfigSvc configSvc;
@inject IStringLocalizer localizer;

some html


partial Program.cs file

srv.AddRazorPages() 
srv.AddControllersWithViews();
app.MapControllers();


Hi @mayi, you current code seems do not have errors, try to clean and rebuild the project. If still not working, pls share a repo which could reproduce your issue.
